# Why isn't this form evaluated inside the lexical context of the let form

Tags: emacs, elisp, lexical-scope

I am trying to make a macro that creates a function that takes S-expresions and evaluates them inside the lexical context of the fixture. Here is the macro I wrote:

```
(defmacro def-fixture (name bindings)
  "Return a function that takes the form to execute but is wrapped between a let of the bindings"
  `(defun ,(intern (symbol-name name)) (body)
     (let (,bindings)
       (unwind-protect
           (progn
             body)))))
```

But when I run it it appears to be executing outside the lexical context I provided

```
(def-fixture test-fixture '(zxvf 1))

(test-fixture '(= zxvf 1))
let: Symbol's value as variable is void: zxvf
```

Btw, I have enabled the variable lexical binding. Any ideas as to what is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with lexical scoping.  Your macro call expands to:

```
(defun test-fixture (body)
  (let ((quote (zxvf 1)))
    (unwind-protect (progn body))))
```

Which is of course not what you intended.  I do not believe that `(test-fixture '(= zxvf 1))` signals the error you cite (i.e. `variable is void`).  Instead, the call signals `(void-function zxvf)` because it tries to evaluate `(zxvf 1)`.  The `(= zxvf 1)` expression is never evaluated, since it's quoted.

You might like to try something more like:

```
(defmacro def-fixture (name bindings)
  "Return a macro that takes the form to execute but is wrapped between a let of the bindings"
  `(defmacro ,name (body)
     `(let (,',bindings)
        (unwind-protect
          (progn
            ,body)))))
```

and then use it as in:

```
(def-fixture test-fixture (zxvf 1))
(test-fixture (= zxvf 1))
```

Comment: I see you are using a nested backquote, was wondering if that was what was needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following note is in the [emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html):

> Also, the code in the body of a defun or defmacro cannot refer to
>   surrounding lexical variables.

It might be what your problem is.

Also I do not know if you need to quote the second argument of `def-fixture`. I used the `macrostep` package to inspect the resulting macro and the result seems better without the quote.

Comment: Thanks!
I'' try to return a lambda and bind the return expresion of the macro to a variable then.